Why were "no longer needed" flags declined?
Comments to this answer are confusing because the answerer actually already addressed the issues with edits. They are, thus, no longer needed and should be removed. I flagged accordingly but it was declined. They don't exceed three comments, so I flagged them individually. 
Why was my flagging not helpful?

I agree those comments can go. Eager to hear the mod judgement on this to decide otherwise.

You did flag those comments recently, right?

@rene Yes just a few days ago.

"They don't exceed three comments, so I flagged them individually" - no? You flagged one singular comment, and you got one singular declined flag. Obligatory note that I did not decline the flag, and this is not a comment on the validity of the decline, but you're off on the number of flags

@Zoe Thanks, not sure what happened, maybe I'm wrong. Remember getting a warning I was too quick, so I might have catched just one. Anyway, still not sure why the one wasn't helpful.

This is a bit weird: you see the declined flag but don't see how many flags you raised? Aren't we talking about this page? Wouldn't each flag be listed individually?

Just make sure to flag these comments once your question is cleaned up.

@AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні Right, they would be "pending" or so, just edited OP. But I can't see which one I've flagged and why it was declined. So you suggesting I should flag again, and make sure to catch all three this time?

I think a flag and this meta post is more than enough signal for a handful of stale comments ;) don't reflag.

@AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні Agreed, thanks.

I've deleted these 3 comments. I don't know why the flag was declined.

Here I was just joking that this question of yours needs the same treatment :P

@jay.sf - “But I can't see which one I've flagged and why it was declined.” - You should be able to see which comments were flagged as you can’t flag a comment twice and you can see a list of every comment you flagged within your profile

I don't see the comments anymore, but I also see that there is no attribution in the edits. That could be a valid reason to decline a NLN flag. If you edit content from the comments into the answer, you have to make sure, you do not plagiarize them.

I quite often flag sequences of comments like that with "In need of moderator intervention" but the comments start "No longer needed (N of M)" and continue with a brief explanation of why the comment is no longer needed.  Sometimes, the same comment works for all of the comments; often, minor tweaking is needed.  I've never had feedback from mods that this is unhelpful.

Sorry, it looks like I mishandled these flags. Upon rereading them, they are all made redundant by the edits, but I didn't realize it at the time. I thought they meant something different at the time.
